# Cufon font-replacement flickers, menu looks ugly

Tags: wordpress, cufon, font-replacement

I'm using the cufon font replacement technique for my site.  it works well, but there is an ugly flicker every time I go to another page within the site.  It's not something users will not notice and it does not look pretty.  Is there a work around for this?  I tried cufon.now() but no good.  So far I've only tested my site in FF and Safari on a Mac (can't even think about how this would look in IE!)

Any tips or help appreciated!  My site is a wordpress site and I'm using the CUFON font-replacement plugin, WP-CUFON

Answer (score 1):

not really a solution to your problem, but you should try some other font replacement techniques like [@font-face](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

Answer (score 1):

There WILL be a small delay in the cufon load, as it runs on document.ready()
As DeanVos suggests, try the @font-face...